# How to format text code using Roslyn?

Tags: roslyn

I went through samples and other questions, people are mostly using `Workspaces`. All I have is a single file and no workspace, how can I format it using `Formatter` static methods ?

Answer (score 2):

You can either create a `Solution` and add the file to a project in that `Solution` (using `Solution.Create()`, or else use the basic formatting provided by `NormalizeWhitespace()`.

Comment: Just to format a single document in a string, do I really need a Solution or Workspace ?

Comment: Yes.  Or else use NormalizeWhitespace.  Note that you can construct a Solution object programmatically.  You don't need an actual .sln file for it.

Comment: I can't find a public version of NormalizeWhitespace in Microsoft.CodeAnalysis package. What is the namespace and/or what package do I need to install into my project? Can somebody provide some sample code for this?